Why do my entities have jittery movement, where their velocities fluctuate wildly between frames?
I'm writing my own simulation for some robots. I want to utilize friction, acceleration, velocity calculations.
Currently, my code looks like this:
float get_robot_new_acceleration(const RobotState& robotState,
                                 const RobotStatistics& robotStatistics,
                                 const float elapsedTime)
{
    // engine power is in watts
    float engineForce = robotStatistics.enginePower;
    if(length(robotState.velocity) > std::numeric_limits<float>::epsilon())
    {
        engineForce = robotStatistics.enginePower / length(robotState.velocity);
    }

    return engineForce / robotStatistics.mass;
}

birunji::Vector2f get_robot_new_velocity(const RobotState& robotState,
                                         const RobotDB& robotDB,
                                         const float elapsedTime)
{
    if(robotState.stability <= 0.f)
    {
        return {0, 0};
    }

    const RobotStatistics& robotStats = robotDB.GetById(robotState.robotId).GetStatistics();

    float acceleration = get_robot_new_acceleration(robotState, robotStats, elapsedTime);

    float frictionForce = TRACTION_COEF * robotStats.mass * GRAVITY;

    Vector2f newVelocity = ((robotState.facing * acceleration) -
                                     (normalise(robotState.velocity) *
                                    std::min(frictionForce, length(robotState.velocity)))) *
                                    (elapsedTime/1000.f);

    return clamp_length(newVelocity, robotStats.maxSpeed);
}

I can't show all my code because there's too much, but I can share the magic numbers above:

GRAVITY is 9.8f
enginePower is 5000.f
mass is between 50.f and 200.f
maxSpeed is between 11.1f and 18.f
elapsedTime is always 16.f, but this isn't a realtime application
TRACTION_COEF is .6f
facing is a normalised vector in the direction the robot wants to go

The problem is that the resulting velocity values fluctuate up and down quite a bit between frames. For example, one frame it will be 0.04f then the next will be 1.23f then back down again.
I'm fairly certain my calculations are right, but I'm not 100% sure. I'm also not sure if I'm facing a precision issue somewhere here?

Why constantly normalise your old velocity, in the new velocity calculation? Should be newVelocity = oldVelocity + acceleration; In this way, according to the classical equations of motion, you can't really go wrong. And when you lump a whole lot of terms into a single line of code, it gets harder to see where the problem lies: sort this out, line by line. Then work backwards until you see where the inputs go wrong, and correct. Take out unecessary terms like friction, and get it working in the most basic way possible. Then worry about optional terms. And write a minimal working example.

It looks like the normalization is an attempt to apply friction that does not exceed the old velocity - it just looks a bit odd applied this way rather than using clamp_length as is done later. I'd agree the old velocity term seems to be missing here - want to write that up as an answer, @Engineer ?
